# yahoo maps api curl settings

Tags: php, curl, yahoo-maps

How should I configure cURL to retrieve data from the yahoo maps api?

Here is the current code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $geocodeurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Which returns a 400 - Bad request HTML file. I've checked `$geocodeurl` and it is a valid XML file, so I figure the problem must be the cURL options?

---

$geocodeurl is

```
 http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?appid=** My App ID **&q=Battle%20Creek,MI&gflags=R
```

Comment: do you use the http:// (or https://) in front of the URL? Maybe you could share the $geocodeurl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK as usual I had misidentified the problem. `cURL` was fine, but the `q=` variable was not being passed through any sort of `urlencode` function correctly.

Worked in my browser because Firefox kindly changed the  to `%20`. With `cURL` you need to be more careful. . . .

Answer (score 1):

i wrote a simple class wrapper to get a basic address as a php object, which might help you get the job done! i also added a google geocoding wrapper.

to answer your question, everything is ok with the url you posted, but yes as you mentioned on your reply you should urlencode the params

```
$query = $this->url."?appid=".$this->appid."&flags=".$this->format;
$query .= "&location=".urlencode($address);
```

here is a link to my wrapper class

https://github.com/mrpollo/Geocoding-API